# How to fix Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a little problem. I'm using backbone.js. I wrote this code like in example:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.App = {
        Views: {},
        Models: {},
        Collections: {}
    }

    App.Collections.Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
         model: App.Models.User,
         url: 'service'
    });
    App.Models.User = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    App.Views.App = Backbone.View.extend({
         initialize: function() {
             console.log( this.collection.toJSON() );
         }
    });

});
</script>
```

Than I started server and in browser console type this:

```
var x =new App.Collections.Users();
x.fetch()
```

And this follows to error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined`. But data is present in response. Details in picture. How to fix this?
Thanks for you answers.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I fixed this bug. The problem was that I created Collection and then the Model. Collections use user model, as working unit, but when I defined this Collection, I did not define Model.

So, if you want to avoid this bug, firstly define a Model and only then define the Collection.

Comment: This was the problem for my case as well, thanks! I am using Gulp, so if anyone's using that please check the sequence of loading.

Comment: Yeah I renamed the model was collection was referencing, causing this error.

Comment: god bless StackOverflow. That error message would've never lead me to that conlusion. I'm also a victim of gulps minifying.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue as well. I created the collection model in `initialize` method instead of defining it as property `model` of the collection.

Comment: Happened even when both were in ready blocks. Had to force a load order.

Comment: If anyone needs it, that would make your code:

    `App.Collections.Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
             initialize: function() {
                       user = new App.Models.User();
             },
             url: 'service'
         });`

***Only the section relevant to the change shown.

Answer (score 27):

Backbone Js has dependency with underscore.js and jQuery, try reordering the resources.
This worked for me:

```
<head>
    <title>Backbone</title>

    <!-- Scripts Load Here-->       
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/underscore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/backbone.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: I see this is a correct one. due to the library import order

Comment: I had similar issue that backbone.min complaining about reading property of undefined i suspected it was a collection issue, it was import order problem lol, Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the following imports are incorrect: (react)

```js
// remove
import e from 'express';
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case  , imports were incorrect

`import { urlencoded } from "express";`
When I removed this statement , it worked  for me.
Check imports of the files you are working with , wheteher something unnecessary imported