# Socket IO: Error: module "msgpack" not found from "/.../redis.js"

Tags: redis, browserify, socket.io, msgpack

Context: 
I am creating a client/server application using `SocketIO`. As the complexity of the problem is relatively high I am implementing both client and sever sides in node JS using its modularity solution (require/exports). To move client code I am using browserify and beefy to test the solution. I have a **OSX Mavericks 10.9.2** and chrome as the browser agent.

Problem: I start the serve with node. I launch the client with beefy and open with chrome the page served  by beefy. Then the following error message is shown (I have check `run-browser.js` instead of `beefy` with similar results):

```
Socket IO: Error: module "msgpack" not found from "/.../redis.js"
```

I have tried to solve the problem by installing `msgpack` but I have obtained worse results. When I install the msgpack a similar message appears for `hiredis` module:

```
Socket IO: Error: module "hiredis" not found from "/.../parser/hiredis.js"
```

After installing `hiredis` finally a message on browser is shown:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
http://localhost:9999/tests-bundle.js:3581
```

Have somebody any idea about how can I proceed?

Thanks in forward, Javier.

Comment: "have obtained worse results" -> post those results. It's clear that you are missing the msgpack module for node, so installing it (like you did) is the first step. If something went wrong during or after the install, that's another issue.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Bert I have edit the question with more information of my steps. I hope they can be useful.

Comment: msgpack and hiredis are indeed needed. Install of both seems fine: good, keep it that way. What's going wrong now, is the deserialization inside redis.js. This post may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19702782/how-to-fix-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-prototype-of-undefined

Comment: Thanks Bert. I was not sure whether it was a good idea to alter third party module (SocketIO libs) :S. From your reference I realice that the message is the same but not the context. My TypeError message refers newly to SocketIO. Now it seems that 'store' is undefined. Do you really think I must inspect and edit SocketIO/redis files??? :S

Comment: Can't help you with that I'm afraid, I don't use SocketIO. But your environment seems fine now. You could google a bit more on "Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined", you are not the first one to encounter this. You might want to close this issue, and post a second one now you know more (and google does not help you). If you suspect a bug in SocketIO/redis, post an issue over there.