# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, browserify

In bundle.js:4982 (which is created using the browserify npm)
I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

The error only appears when I include the express framework here:

```
var shopifyAPI = require('shopify-node-api');
var express = require('express'); // comment this out and it works...

$( document ).ready(function() {

    console.log( "ready!" );
...
```

How do I solve this error?

Note: [How to fix Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19702782/how-to-fix-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-prototype-of-undefined)
This stackoverflow question is very similar except I don't know if I'm using a collection and/or model... or how to fix my problem from their answer...

Comment: Have you written jQuery code on Server?

Comment: yes I have, i am using http-server

Comment: Can you help me? I have literally been stuck on this for hours

Comment: Express won't work on the client, as it is a server-side framework.

Comment: but the shopify-node-api module requires express

Comment: I think you are supposed to use the shopify api on the server side and only let the client interact with it using get/post/put/delete requests. Exposing your api key/access token/shared secret at once to the client doesn't sound like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the shopify module in your client JavaScript. `shopify-node-api` is only meant to be used in your server JavaScript.

You have to setup your own API, that uses this module. I recommend opening a new question, presenting what you try to achieve, and what you already did to solve your problem.

However, your error is currently not resolvable.