# Exception: cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined in polyfill js

Tags: javascript, angular, polyfills

I am facing the above error in angular4 application while deploying. Locally it works fine. I am not sure of any possible reason for it. Has anyone faced similar issue ?

[image]

Comment: any code to along with this? Please and thank you

Comment: It can be a circular dependency. Just follow the link that console gives you and you will see what's the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19702782/how-to-fix-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-prototype-of-undefined)

Comment: missing dependency.